# How to avoid hardcoding business entities' values in MVC core views' conditional code?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

A lot of my code inside views seems to be taking the below form when I want to show specific partial views (or some other clientside code) based on some master table value in the database -

```
<div id="@claim.Id" class="ReimbursementClaims">
    @if (claim.ClaimStatus.SubmissionStatus == "Unsubmitted")
        {
            <partial name="~/Views/Claims/_ClaimDetailsEditor.cshtml" />
        }
    else (claim.ClaimStatus.SubmissionStatus == "Approved")
        {
            <partial name="~/Views/Claims/_ClaimDetailsReadonly.cshtml" />
        }
</div>
```

The backend database contains a Claim table and a related ClaimStatusMaster table. The ClaimStatusMaster table is a master table meaning that it exists just to store static values like "Approved", "Unsubmitted". For example -

```
create table Claim (Id int, ClaimStatusId int) --ClaimStatusId is a foreignkey linking to ClaimStatusMaster
create table ClaimStatusMaster (id int, SubmissionStatus varchar(20))
insert into ClaimStatusMaster values (2, 'Unsubmitted')
insert into ClaimStatusMaster values (1, 'Approved')
insert into ClaimStatusMaster values (3, 'Rejected') --etc
```

As you see, the appropriate view to be shown completely depends on the value of ClaimStatusMaster table's SubmissionStatus field. But if SubmissionStatus changes for any reason, the ifelse conditions in the view will break.Further this whole setup seems like a code smell. So, I am trying to figure out how to code this better to minimize such coupling while also be able to conditionally show the appropriate views based on SubmissionStatus values. How can I achieve this?

PS: I can probably put the ifelse code in a controller but it seems to result in more or less the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances, I would avoid putting any logic in the view. However, I think some simple logic like you have that chooses an alternate presentation based on some property passed to it by the controller, is OK.

That being said, an alternative to this would be to create an extension method that handles this logic. All you do is call the extension and it will return the full name of the partial.

Comment: Thank you, how to avoid the hardcoding though?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you think you are hardcoding. You will simply move the business logic into extension. The logic for SubmissionStatus will be encapsulated there and not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is directly use `ClaimStatusId` in your logic . You can create the Enum :

```
public enum SubmissionStatus
{
    Approved = 1 ,
    Unsubmitted =2 ,
    Rejected =3 ,
}
```

And then write the logic in view :

```
<div id="@claim.Id" class="ReimbursementClaims">
@if ((int)claim.ClaimStatusId  == (int)SubmissionStatus.Unsubmitted)
{
    <partial name="~/Views/Claims/_ClaimDetailsEditor.cshtml" />
}
```

But of course you should sync the enum value with database `ClaimStatusMaster` values .